# Split video screen into 3 equal parts

Tags: video

I'm working on a project that will be presented on 3 screens. The idea is that each screen in showing a part of the screening video, which means the upper display shows the upper 1/3 of the video screen, the middle display shows the middle part of the video, and the lower display the lower part of the video.

So my question is how can I cut the video screen in 3 equal parts, and with which program?

Thanks for each reply!

Comment: This question might get better answers if you supply a little more information. There is a lot of software that can do it, ranging from free command-line tools to very expensive NLEs. What software do you have, how is the video going to be delivered, is it being saved to a file or are you wanting this to happen to a live stream?

Comment: @stib I'm using After Effects CS6 and Premier Pro CS6. The video is going to be saved as a file.

Comment: Are the screens driven by one device or three devices?

Comment: yes, they are driven by 3 devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your footage in one timeline, with the sequence setting set to the combined dimensions of all the screens (so the width of one screen across × three times the height). So if they're 1080p screens you'll be looking at 1920 × 3240.

Now make three sequences, each with the resolution of one playback screen, e.g 1920 × 1080. Take your original sequence and lay it into these timelines (as a nested sequence).

Adjust the motion properties of the clip in the first sequence so that the top of the clip lines up with the top of the frame, then in the next sequence align the middle of the clip with the middle of the frame and in the last sequence align the bottom of the clip with the bottom of the frame.

Now you have three sequences that align as you wish. The beauty of nesting the combined sequence is that you can make changes without having to synchronise three separate sequences.